# How to split a word 2010 document and keep the automatic table of contents?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have a word document I want to split into 3 files and save them to different pdf files.

The problem is that when I split the file the automatic table of content insists of changing all the numbers in the content table to "Error! Bookmark not defined".

I know I can create a table of contents manually but it is a very long one and I'd like to use the automatic generated table. Maybe there is a way to detach it somehow from the automatic updater?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your whole table of contents and press Ctrl+ Shift + F9. It should turn it into plain text. Then you can fiddle with it to make your PDF files.

I just found this answer, and I don't have a document with a table of contents handy to test it. You can try it and tell me whether it works. This answer was given for a Mac, so the shortcut might differ.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I already "solved" it with print screens which is ugly. Now I tried your solution and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You can use RD fields to allow Word to create a TOC based on separate Word docs.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little more please. Short answers don't tend to be good answers. Explanations help make great answers.